# Extracting array from JSON using Swift

Tags: json, swift

Loads of Java experience but a relative n00b with Swift.  I have the following JSON, from which I'm failing to extract the "images" array, which could have as many as 3 images...

```
   {
      "status" : "OPEN",
      "description" : “…”,
      "name" : “…”,
      "owner" : 1,
      "images" : [
        {
          "id" : 1,
          "path" : "\/uploads\/1-60003456.jpeg"
        }
      ],
      "created" : 1459135829000,
      "id" : 1
    }
```

I keep running into a host of compile-time and runtime errors.  For example, this code from the SwiftyJSON docs:

```
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
    if(key == "images"){
        let myImages = subJson.array
        print(myImages![0]["path"])
    }
}
```

Correctly prints out the value for "path", yet attempting to save that value in my [String] images:

```
images.append(myImages![0]["path"] as String)
```

Gives error "Cannot subscript a value of type JSON with an index of type String"

XCode tells me subJson is an NSDictionary for "images" (or is it an array of dictionaries?), but, when I try to cast it as such, I get "Cannot convert value of type JSON to type NSDictionary in coersion".

I'm sure it's a simple syntactic error but, at this point, I'm just going back and forth between the various errors.  Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use downcasting, SwiftyJSON has already done this work. SwiftyJSON has an optional getter for a string representation of the object it has already parsed:

```
myImages![0]["path"].string
```

Since it's an Optional you want to safely unwrap it:

```
if let path = myImages![0]["path"].string {
    images.append(path)
}
```

If `myImages![0]["path"]` is not a String, then SwiftyJSON offers you as many optional getters as there are JSON types:

```
myImages![0]["path"].array
myImages![0]["path"].dictionary
myImages![0]["path"].int
```

etc.

With SwiftyJSON you can also subscript directly:

```
if let firstImagePath = json["images"][0]["path"].string {
    // use "firstImagePath"
}
```

To conclude, another kind of loop:

```
if let images = json["images"] {
    for image in images {
        if let path = image["path"].string {
            // use "path"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks, Eric.